# How can I store an array of values into one index document in Zend Lucene?

Tags: php, indexing, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I've got a database with a list of registrations. Each of the registrations has `0..*` tickets codes. How can I store it into an index document to be able to find a registration by one of the codes?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I put all tickets into one column `tickets` and I store ticket codes there and each of them divided by space. I made that column with type `Text` ([Understanding Field Types](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html)). So, it allows me to search by the tickets and registration information.